# how can see who's online using timestamp function?

Tags: php, mysql

i am having problem showing how many users are online using timestamp function. what i am doing is storing last active time in 'lastactivity' database column using time(); function and updating it whenever user refreshes the page. here's code for showing lastactivity :-

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");            
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$last = $array['lastactivity'];
echo $last;
}
?>
```

i am just confused what condition to use with 'if' if possible to seperate out those who are not active for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that `array` isn't a reserved word in PHP.

Comment: time(); is storing it as 1387801483 also changing it other name doesn't help.

Comment: So it's epoch time - just compare with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` to get elapsed seconds.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can do it faster:

```
 select * from users where timediff( now(), lastactivity ) > "00:05:00";
```

Comment: I guess it works either way - show those who aren't active (>) or those who are (<)

Comment: this does not show any output :-<?
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where timediff( now(), lastactivity ) > '00:05:00'");            
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$last = $array['lastactivity'];
echo $last;
}
?>

Comment: Try `select timediff( now(), lastactivity ) from users;` on the cmd line before you put it into PHP. I may have the format of the result wrong.